# Match all numbers greater than 36 using regex?

Tags: regex

How can I match all numbers greater than 36 to any bigger number?

I tried this expression:

```
[4-9]\d+|\d{3,}
```

Problem is this will select all number greater than 40 but I need 37, 38 and 39 as well, How can i achieve that?

**NOTE:** My query is different: I couldn't understand from there so I asked my own question and my query is 100% different. Being similar in some ways is another thing than being duplicate. Peace out.

Comment: @Jan So what do you want me to do, if I have similar query and unable to understand the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply adding `3[7-9]` (to match 37, 38, 39) will work:

```
3[7-9]|[4-9]\d+|\d{3,}
```

**UPDATE**

To prevent matching numbers like `0001`:

```
3[7-9]|[4-9]\d+|[1-9]\d{2,}
```

Comment: Isn't this going to match '0001' as well?

Comment: @user1016274, Yes it does. `\d{3,}` part should be modified. Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @falsetru this regex is perfectly fine but while i was experimenting with my script, I noticed that from '370' to '399' numbers wont be selected.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution:

```
37|38|39|[4-9]\d+|\d{3,}
```

or to exclude numbers starting with 0:

```
\b(37|38|39|[4-9]\d+|(?!0)\d{3,})\b
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for range between 10 - 99

```
[3-9][7-9]|[4-9]\d
```